# AWS Lambda - Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'jmespath'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am working with aws lambda using serverless framework, I changed the runtime from `nodejs8.10` to `nodejs10.x`, then I got an errortrace,

```
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'jmespath'","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'jmespath'","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:36:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)","    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)","    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)","    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"]}
```

What is the cause of this issue and how can get it fixed?

Comment: Did you find a solution, running into the same problem...

Comment: I was running into this where the lambda would invoke locally (on Windows) but report a failure to find the handler module once deployed.  My serverless.yml was locating the handler function with a backslash in the path name. functions\myHandler.myFunction. It worked after changing to a forward slash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hit the same problem `Error: Cannot find module 'jmespath'` and solved it.

Do you use `aws-sdk` via node_modules? like follows

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
```

If so you just remove aws-sdk from node_modules.

remove aws-sdk for yarn

```
yarn remove aws-sdk
```

remove aws-sdk for npm

```
npm uninstall aws-sdk
```

`aws-sdk` has been included to lambda since nodejs10.
see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `./` in front of your module name. I changed my name from `require("xxx")` to `require("./xxx")` and it worked again. In my case, the local module file i wanted to add (`xxx.js`) is on the same level as the `index.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to add that as a preliminary step before adjusting your path, check and verify your dependencies listed in your package.json(s) files.
I've seen this error "Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'something' occur in the aws cloudwatch logs. 
It happened because my project has multiple subprojects/subfolders with their own package.json files.  Ensure that module is properly referenced in the subproject's package.json.
In local dev, you might have the dependency cited in your base/global package.json, and thinking it works -- but when you deploy the lambda the npm install that occurs during build does not include the newly required module because its not referenced in the local subproject's package.json.

Answer (score 1):

In the root serverless project folder

```
npm i --save <npm module name missing>
```

Comment: To others reading this answer: double-check that all your project's dependencies are present in the `package.json` file. Sounds obvious, but in this case, it's possible that `npm` is using `jmespath` from a parent project, or from the global `node_modules/` you have in your machine, and they are not getting installed in AWS since they are not present in your project's `package.json` file.

Comment: yet another good reason not to ```npm install -g``` ever!

Answer (score 0):

Well encountered the same issue in our project too.
It was issue in the same of file import.
Our file name `xabc.js` and in imported as `Xabc.js`
VScode was not complaining and was showing proper import

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that this `jmespath` library was actually missing(and some others, too) from uploaded `node_modules` folder.
Verified this by downloading zip(as the source was too big) and did not found there `jmespath` nor `aws-sdk` libraries.
Solved it by installing dependencies with `npm i` and re-uploading lambda with updated node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

If 'nodejs' folder  is not there in Lambda Layer, create 'nodejs' and any file so that while executing the function, lambda will create zip file with entire node_modules packages inside 'nodejs' folder of Layer. If it is empty it will not execute. I hope it will resolve the issue. In my case it is working fine.